# Unresponsive UI Elements after closing NSWindow

Tags: macos, nswindow, nscontrol

Last week I spent a good amount of time fiddling around with the following problem. I solved it but since I couldn't find an answer here and I want to share my solution for anybody who runs into this.

---

**Problem:** My application runs in the background (menubar) and its main `NSWindow` contains all the preferences of my application. You close the `NSWindow` by clicking the close button in the top-left. After closing the `NSWindow` and reopening it, all the `NSControl`s were not visually responding. The actions worked accordingly, but they where not updating.

I tried the following:

- Unchecking ***"Release on close"*** in IB for `NSWindow`
- Reloading `NSWindow` from NIB
- Strong references for all `NSControl`s
- Calling ***"Become first responder"*** on `NSControl`s
- Reloading all the parenting `NSView`s
- Implementing all the delegates hooking up each `NSControl` (Worked for `NSControl`, but was way too much work to use it for each and every one)
- Disabling and then reenabling the `NSControl`s

I'll post my solution below for the records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution to this problem was to subclass `NSWindow` and overwrite the following methods:

```
- (void)performClose:(id)sender{
    [self orderOut:nil];
}

- (void)close{
    [self orderOut:nil];
}
```

Now the `NSWindow` is **hidden** / **ordered** out and you just have to order it back in when displaying it.